# AfterEffects: How to make audio sine waves like this?

Tags: after-effects, audio, effects

Alright, there are many tutorials on audio spectrums in AE, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_-aycDYsJM

I want to make a visualizer like this, however, where the waves more mimic sine waves: https://dribbble.com/shots/3364622-Sound-Waves

Ive tried flipping this switch in AE, but this doesnt give me the desired result, especially w the secondary waves of less opacity next to the main wave-

[image]

How can I accomplish this and have it be reactive to audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the analog lines, but turn up the number of frequency bands, a *LOT*. Like to a thousand or so. To get single lines use side a or side b in the side options. You can also change the upper and lower frequencies to focus more on parts of the audio that are interesting. Then repeat with different settings to achieve multiple lines.